# How unique is thin/reduced QR decomposition without $R_{ii}>0$ condition?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ real matrix ($m\ge n$) with independent columns, and let $Q_1 R_1 = Q_2 R_2$ be two thin/reduced QR decompositions of $A$, i.e. $Q$ ($m\times n$) has orthonormal columns and $R$ ($n\times n$) is upper-triangular. If we relax the condition that the diagonal elements of the $R$ matrices be positive, then the **decomposition is not unique**. But how exactly are $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ related? (same question for $R_1$ and $R_2$)

In the square case ($m=n$), I can prove that $R_1 = SR_2$ and $Q_1 = Q_2S$, where $S$ is a signature matrix (diagonal matrix with $\pm1$ on the diagonal). However, **I'm stuck trying to prove this for thin matrices** ($m>n$). The sticking point in my proof is the assumption that the $R$ matrices are invertible (or simply that they have nonzero diagonals).

I'd appreciate any pointers to a good reference on this or sketches of a proof. This should be a standard result from linear algebra, but I haven't found a book which fully addresses this ([these notes](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Ekkloste/cs515fa14/qr-uniqueness.pdf) come close, but they don't explain how $A$ having independent columns implies $R$ is invertible).

---

**Why do I relax the positive diagonal condition?** Several numerical algorithms for QR decomposition, including those from [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.qr.html) and [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr.html), do not have this restriction. I need to be certain that these decompositions can be fixed/made unique via a signature matrix $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The sticking point in my proof is the assumption that the  matrices are invertible (or  simply that they have nonzero diagonals).

Notice for any choice of $k$
$0\lt \det\big(A^T A\big) = \det\big(R_k^TQ_k^TQ_k R_k\big) =\det\big(R_k^T R_k\big) = \det\big(R_k\big)^2 = \prod_{j=1}^n \big(r_{j,j}^{(k)}\big)^2$
so the diagonals must be non-zero

I assume you are working over $\mathbb R$ as your mention of a signature matrix suggests you that you are working over $\mathbb R$ not $\mathbb C$

Comment: Indeed, I am working over $\mathbb R$, I'll make an edit. The only part of your proof I didn't follow is the first step: $0<\det(A^TA)$. Why is that?

Comment: consider any $\mathbf x \neq \mathbf 0$ then $A\mathbf x = \mathbf y\neq \mathbf 0$ since $A$'s columns are linearly independent.  So  $\mathbf x^TA^TA\mathbf x = \mathbf y^T\mathbf y \gt 0$ so $A^T A$ is positive definite -- but if you prefer you can just conclude that $A^TA$ is invertible and put a modulus sign around everything.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!